# Javascript Error in themes/javascript/compressed/jquery/plugins/ee_filebrowser.js

Tags: javascript

I have an “add file” link in a plain template. When I click it, I get:

`Timestamp: 2/18/14, 11:43:40 PM
Error: TypeError: d is undefined
Source File: https://preview.mycustomsite.com/index.php?S=e6d26fe1e6d862912992a7dfe770a712aa694471&D=cp&C=javascript&M=combo_load&ui=datepicker,resizable,draggable,droppable&plugin=ee_url_title,tmpl,ee_table,scrollable,scrollable.navigator,ee_filebrowser,ee_fileuploader,markitup,toolbox.expose,overlay&file=underscore,files/publish_fields,json2,cp/publish,cp/publish_tabs,cp/publish_admin&v=1392357549
Line: 364`

Short of disabling plugins one at a time until it works, has anyone ever had this issue?

UPDATE: I copied the files and the database to my local environment and it works just fine. It is still broken on the staging server. I diff'ed the javascript and HTML files and the only difference is the v=????? numbers.

UPDATE: its because the EE ajax loader is loading some javascript asynchronously over HTTP, yet the site is loading over HTTPS. Now I need to figure out how to get it to load over HTTPS.

Comment: Could you paste your template code? Specifically the code for [what I assume is] the Channel Form?

Comment: I looked around, but didn't see any template code. Any tips?

Comment: Where are you getting this message? I'm assuming you are getting it when you view a template from your browser, right? I'm asking to see the code you have in your template that is giving you this error.

Comment: Sure, but its not a template AFAIK, its the admin panel. Where are those templates typically found? http://cl.ly/image/0Z0m2v2E033b http://cl.ly/U1GY

Comment: Ah, if it's CP then we don't need the templates. But it would have been good to specify that. What page of the CP are you on? What addons are in play?

Comment: Its on a "Channel Publish" - http://cl.ly/image/3Q402N1c0l13. Modules here: http://cl.ly/image/1M2W0Q2J2J0N

Comment: @JeremyGimbel I found was related to HTTP ajax load instead of HTTPS. Any ideas how to control this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a far more complex problem than I expected. The site was running over HTTPS. It had a load balancer in front of 2 web servers. The SSL was being terminated at the load balancer, with non-SSL traffic being sent to the web servers. While the site was configured for SSL use, somewhere a REDIRECT was being generated for the Control Panel's asynchronous javascript loading. The REDIRECT was from HTTPS to HTTP. This was causing load errors in the browser, which was manifesting itself as the error above. When the load balancer was taken out of the loop, it worked fine.